# How to do health check for nginx and rails application

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3, health-monitoring

I wrote a rails application for commerce and I am worried about the application is stable or not. I used nginx + passenger to deploy the application.

I want to know what's the common health check solution for rails application.

Answer (score 2):

Give https://github.com/blythedunham/health_monitor a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty common one that supports several different checks:

https://github.com/ianheggie/health_check